# TimeStamp to date conversion failure

Tags: java, timestamp

i'm trying to convert timeStamp to date i'm having a problem which i have no idea why it's happening

```
created_time // 1489095567  **actual value of timestamp : Thu, 09 Mar 2017 21:39:27 GMT
Date date = new Date(Long.valueOf(created_time)); 
System.out.println(date +" : "+ Long.valueOf(created_time));  //Sun Jan 18 11:08:15 GMT+05:30 1970 : 1489095567
```

anyone can point out why conversion is failing?

Comment: If your timestamp is coming out of a database, (or other source), check that the epoch is the same as jre

Comment: @santoshPatil no error, only the conversion is not correct you can see the output of `date`

Comment: @jr593  yeah i just checked it and it's the same as JRE

Comment: You should also consider switching to the new DateTime API: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It seems that the timestamp is, in second so multiply 1000 to convert it to millisecond**

Example :

```
long created_time = 1489095567; // **actual value of timestamp : Thu, 09 Mar 2017 21:39:27 GMT
Date date = new Date(created_time * 1000);
System.out.println(date + " : " + created_time);  //Sun Jan 18 11:08:15 GMT+05:30 1970 : 1489095567
```

Comment: yeah that was it, i converted it before multiplying right here: https://www.epochconverter.com , they showed correct date so i thought default value is fine. thanks